# nginx Location regex for wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, nginx, location, alias

I'm converting my site from .net to Wordpress, and an import has set the img reference to a lot of my pictures to urls starting with `/2014/01/articlefiles`, `2014/02/articlefiles`, all the way back to 2003. etc.

All the pictures on the webserver is located in the same folder

```
/var/www/sharedfolders/indhold/articlefiles/
```

Is it possible to make a location that answers

```
/yyyy/mm/articlefiles/picturename.ext
```

(Where yyyy = any year & mm = any month in numbers.)

and points to `/var/www/sharedfolders/indhold/articlefiles/picturename.ext`

I tried a lot of different ways.

**Tried this:** (*Still no luck*)

```
location ~ ^/(2003|2004|2005|2006|2007|2008|2009|2010|2011|2012|2013|2014)/(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)/articlefiles/(.*)
{
    alias /var/www/sharedfolders/articlefiles/$3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it my self.

```
location ~ ^/20[0-1][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/articlefiles/?(.*) {
    alias /var/www/sharedfolders/indhold/articlefiles/$1;
     access_log off;
     log_not_found off;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}
```